# Appending a datetime stamp in en excel file using Interop using C#

Tags: c#, excel, save, excel-interop

I'm looking to save a excel file to an specific location with current datetime stamp appended to the file name using Microsoft Excel Interop. I'm am able to save the file without the datetime stamp but every time I try to append datetime stamp, I get an exception that file could not be accessed. Here is my code

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + @"D:\Beeper.csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
//xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"D:\Beeper.csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
//System.IO.File.Move(@"D:\Beeper.csv", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
//xlWorkBook.SaveCopyAs(System.DateTime.Now);

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

I have tried multiple combination but cant figure out what is happening. Is there any other way to do it. And It has to be console application only.

Comment: try 
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(string.Format("D:\\{0}_Beeper.csv", System.DateTime.Now.ToString()),......)

I believe your code is failing because you adding the timestamp before the filename

Comment: I have tried adding it after as well but still same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that DateTime.Now.ToString() might be returning you 
something like mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss and so the '/' characters are illegal in the file name.
Try

```
 SaveAs(string.Format("D:\\Beeper_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")));
```